# IBM ESSO (AccessAgent) breaking "Reset Password" page?

Tags: authentication, web, single-sign-on, forgot-password

One of our customers uses IBM's Security Access Manager (ISAM) for Enterprise Single Sign-On (ESSO), which uses a piece of software on the client called [AccessAgent](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/access-mgr-esso). From what I understand it's basically a glorified password manager.

This customer uses the software to autofill the username/password prompts on our web site so that they can log in; however, the software also tries to do this on the "Reset Password" page which comes up in the event that the software has a different password stored than what the user actually has. When users hit the reset page, AccessAgent automatically redirects them to the home page for some reason.

The first thing I tried was renaming the field from "username" to something non-semantic in hopes of throwing the software off. This worked for a few months but it has apparently 'learned' again that "hey, people put their e-mail address in here, I'll try to log them in!".

Past efforts to train individual users to turn off the software have not worked, and we continue to get a lot of "your password reset page doesn't work" tech support requests.

**My question is this:** Does anyone have any experience with this software, and is there a way to disable it for my password reset page? Either via HTTP header or  tag or something?